# Trouble compiling scala code using the astyanax client

Tags: scala, cassandra, astyanax

```
val CF_USER_STATS = new ColumnFamily[java.lang.Long, String]("Standard2", LongSerializer.get, StringSerializer.get)

val m: MutationBatch = keyspace.prepareMutationBatch()

m.withRow(CF_USER_STATS, "acct1234").incrementCounterColumn("CounterColumn1", 1)

m.execute()
```

The above is creating a column family meant to be used as a counter in Cassandra.  For whatever reason, compilation is failing with the following:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.netflix.astyanax.model.ColumnFamily[Long,String]
[error]  required: com.netflix.astyanax.model.ColumnFamily[Comparable[_ >: String with Long <: Comparable[_ >: String with Long <: Comparable[_ >: String with Long <: java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable,String]
[error] Note: Long <: Comparable[_ >: String with Long <: Comparable[_ >: String with Long <: Comparable[_ >: String with Long <: java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable, but Java-defined class ColumnFamily is invariant in type K.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Comparable[_ >: String with Long <: Comparable[_ >: String with Long <: Comparable[_ >: String with Long <: java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]   m.withRow(CF_USER_STATS, "acct1234")
```

Answer (score 0):

Astyanax ColumnFamily syntax with description

```
ColumnFamily<String, String> CF = 
     new ColumnFamily<String, String>(
     "Standard1",              // Column Family Name
     StringSerializer.get(),   // Key Serializer
     StringSerializer.get());  // Column Serializer
```

Now in your case, you have mentioned your rowkey as Long type and column as String and while updating the counter you are using key as your string, that's why this **type mismatch**.